# Discord.py, bot doesn't play any mp3 file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

DISCLAIMER: I've reposted this question, and deleted the original question, as a guy gave a silly answer, reducing the visibility of the question.

Basically, i'm migrating my bot to the rewrite version of discord.py .

I'm testing the bot with just a few functions from the previous one, now i'm testing the audio functionalities with the on_voice_state_update() event, the bot should play an audio when someone joins a channel.

I writed the event like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  global bot_voice_status
  global tts_status
  global vc
  if(bot_voice_status == 0 and tts_status == 0 and member.display_name.find("St3veB0T") == -1):
   if(before.channel == None): 
    rand = randint(0, len(os.listdir("audio"))-1)    
    ix = 0
    for filename in os.listdir("audio"):
        if(ix == rand):    
            c = 0
            try:
                vc = await after.channel.connect()
                c = 1
            except:
                break
            if(c == 1):
                try:
                    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio((os.path.join("audio",filename)))
                    vc.play(audio_source, after=lambda e: print('done', e))
                    while vc.is_playing():
                       await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    vc.stop()
                    await vc.disconnect()
                    break
                except:
                    await vc.disconnect()
                    break
        ix = ix + 1
```

What this code does is, check if a user joined a voice channel, joins the actual voice channel, then it tries to play a random audio file from a folder, after that it should leave the voice channel.

The problem is that, when i join a channel, the bot joins, but doesn't play any audio and doesn't write any output or error on terminal. After waiting for some time, i see that the bot doesn't even disconnect from the channel.

I'm completely lost at this point...i really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Btw, i'm testing on Windows machine with python 3.7.3 64-bit

UPDATE:

When doing logging i get this warning:

```
2019-10-18 15:26:39,757:DEBUG:discord.client: Dispatching event socket_raw_send
2019-10-18 15:26:39,932:DEBUG:discord.client: Dispatching event socket_raw_receive
2019-10-18 15:26:39,933:DEBUG:discord.gateway: For Shard ID None: WebSocket Event: {'t': None, 's': None, 'op': 11, 'd': None}
2019-10-18 15:26:39,933:DEBUG:discord.client: Dispatching event socket_response
2019-10-18 15:26:41,605:WARNING:discord.gateway: Shard ID None has stopped responding to the gateway. Closing and restarting.
```

I'm using discord.py==1.2.3 with websockets==6.0 and aiohttp==3.3.0

Comment: As a side note: you can get a random item from a list with the `choice()` function. I.e. `import random` => `random.choice(os.listdir())`.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to the new discord.py version `1.2.4`, there was a bug concerning `VoiceChannel.connect()` in the previous version: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats_new.html#v1-2-4

Comment: Ty, that was the problem, i looked for help on the official Discord API server, and they told me it was a websockets ip that changed. So all i need to do is upgrade to 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the FFMPeG improperly installed. Try to install it manually

> https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

This is the official page, you need to download it and paste it on Local Disk. Finally of installing it you need to put it on the PATH, searching the `system properties` (if you are on Windows), and editing `Environment Variables`.